# Finding the index of the first element of a list in another list

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
main_list = ['4', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
my_list = ['4', '5', '6']
```

My question is, how to find index of my_list in main_list?

The integers in my_list must be in consecutive order in main_list.

I tried using `main_list.index(my_list[0])` but if there are more than one of a specific element, it returns the wrong index number. The result I need to get is 4, however with `main_list.index(my_list[0])` it'll just give 0 as its index.

If there is any need for clarification, I can edit the post with additional details. Sorry, English is not my first language.

Comment: Iterate over three item slices of ```main_list``` and compare them to ```my_list```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```
for i in range(len(main_list)-len(my_list)):
    if main_list[i:i+len(my_list)] == my_list:
        index = i 
        break
```

This should work for all possible types that could go in the lists.

Comment: you should declare index as  `index = -1`  for the case when it is not found.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert both lists into a string using [`join()` function](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm) and iteratively compare the strings to find a match.

EDIT: Made a change for it two work for multi-digit numbers. Added a float case as well.

For example:

```
main_list = ['4', '1', '2', '3', '40.1', '52', '61', '7', '8', '9', '10']
my_list = ['40.1', '52', '61']
index = -1

for i in range(len(main_list)):
    if '#'.join(main_list[i:i+len(my_list)]) == '#'.join(my_list):
        index = i
        break

print(index)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's a great way to solve this problem.

Comment: If this worked for you, please mark as answer. Thanks!

Comment: What if there are float numbers in the list though? Then a different method would surely need to be used?

Comment: No, this works for float as well. You can try it out.

Comment: Added a case for float and multi-digit numbers as well

Comment: If main list contains the sequence ['45', '6'], before the required match, this would give you a false match. Try using non empty string for the join, such as "@".

Comment: @SimonCallan answer has been edited to account for this case.

Comment: @RohinGopalakrishnan I don't see it, unless I'm missing a space in the join. It looks like a value of '40.15261' would generate a false positive for your example.

Comment: @SimonCallan that's right. I have edited the solution to account for this.

Comment: @karleh If this solution works for you, please mark it as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you would like an algorithm solution:

```
def Find(haystack, needle):
    n, h = len(needle), len(haystack)
    assert n <= h

    for i in range(h):
        if h - i <= n: break
        count = 0
        for i_, j in zip(range(i, i + n), range(n)):
            if haystack[i_] == needle[j]:
                count += 1
        if count == n: return i

    return -1
```

Answer (score 0):

A much more effective one liner :

```
print ','.join(main_list).find(','.join(my_list)) - ''.join(main_list).find(''.join(my_list))
```

Converts them to strings with the elements separated by commas, finds the occurrence, then subtracts the occurrence found when the commas aren't there, and you have your answer.